# Use a local date in option

Tags: rundeck

I've scheduled a Rundeck (3.3.8) job at 15:00 choosing with my local timezone (Europe/Rome).

In job argument I've set

```
-lastStartDate ${DATE-1:yyyyMMddHHmmss}
```

[image]

[image]

for saying 'one day ago'.

The problem is that DATE is UTC, so when it starts at 3 pm my time, it says LastStartDate=20210425**13**0000 while I need it to be in my local time, so 15.

What can I do?

Comment: Hi! could you share a basic job definition example and how you are passing that argument? Maybe via API? Thanks :-)

Comment: Don't know how to do that via API, so I've added a couple of pics, hope they are enough. I'm using that 'et_products' job ad job reference in another job, and there I've set that argument. Thanks.

Comment: I assume that the server where rundeck works is configured with your local time, right? If not, you can "force" Rundeck to use an specific timezone adding -Duser.timezone (https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2072#issuecomment-252400455) parameter on the rundeckd file (https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/system-properties.html#rpm-and-deb)

Comment: Let me add the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Rundeck to use a specific timezone adding `-Duser.timezone` parameter on the rundeckd file, [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/system-properties.html#rpm-and-deb) you can see how to add the parameter, take a look at [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2072#issuecomment-252400455).

In your case would be:

```
RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Rome"
```

And restart the Rundeck service.